# When in iOS sandbox mode, the in-app purchase popup does not display the icon

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing an issue where the in-app-purchase popup isn't displaying the correct icon in sandbox mode.

I've configured the default icon in Unity 2021.3.22f and made sure the app icon image sets are properly set up in Xcode.

However, even after changing the app icon, it still doesn't appear correctly in the in-app-purchase popup.

The similar case can be found at the link below.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702503

I would like to verify if the answer provided in that link is correct, but since the app is currently live on the market, I cannot activate it for testing purposes.

Could you please assist me with resolving this issue?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cvE1.jpg)

Try : Set Default icon in Unity Player Setting

Expected : The image registered in the payment popup appears in the part where the icon is displayed.

Resulted : The image registered for the icon in the payment popup is not appearing.